# Is it possible to open an ios app from a Facebook Fan Page through deep-linking?

Tags: ios, facebook

We enabled deep-linking for our ios app. It is working perfectly for wallposts / timeline posts.

But our client created a fan page from where he give some gifts (virtual economy gifts)
Example:

"Take these free coins here : **insert URL here** "

When we click that URL from the Facebook App on IOS, it is sending us to app Store.
Again, we have it working for wallposts and timeline posts.

And that URL is working on PC: it opens their facebook App and gives the coins.

I've looked at the description of deep-linking in the Facebook Developper page. Here is what it says:

**"(Facebook Login required) If enabled, links in newsfeed/timeline stories will launch this native app, and the original url will be passed as part of the Intent's data."**

So we thought maybe it was just impossible.

Anyone has been able to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, implement a URI scheme in your app and use that as the link. For example `myapp://parameters/go/here`.

You will hit the issue of what happens when the app is not installed, in which case you want to send them to the app-store. So set the facebook link to a page on your server that redirects to the URI scheme (`myapp://whatever`), with a JavaScript timer that also redirects to the app-store install page (you can also redirect to Android install page based on User Agent if you have an Android app too).

How it works: If the app is installed and the `myapp://` redirect opens your app, the web-page will close and won't have chance to redirect to the store. If the app is not installed the `myapp://` won't do anything and after 0.5 seconds or whatever you set it to, the page will redirect to the app-store purchase page.

Another thing you can do is put in smart-app-banners. This pops up a banner at the top of the web-page that offers the user to go to the app-store (if it's not installed) or open the app (if it is installed). See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

You will probably have to experiment with these techniques in order to figure out what works best for your situation.